# How to prove this geometry problem mathematically?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Triangle ∆ABC is arbitrary. Side AC is a diameter to a semicircle, and M marks the point in the middle of this semicircle arc. Side BC is a diameter to a semicircle, and N marks the point in the middle of this semicircle arc. O is a point on side AB, and AO = OB.

Conjecture: OM = ON  and $\measuredangle$MON = 90°

Comment: One should use the *exterior* semicircle  both times, i suppose

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, point $M$ is on the bisector of $AC$, outside the triangle and a distance $\frac{1}{2} |AC|$ away from $AC$?

Comment: @Hagen: it seems either the two exterior semicircles or the two interior semicircles, but not a mixture.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. Indeed, these are exterior semicircles.

Answer (score 3):

With the vertices represented by complex numbers $a,b,c$, we find $m=a+\alpha(c-a)$, $n=c+\alpha(b-c)$, $o=\frac{a+b}2$ with $\alpha=\frac{1+i}2$.
Now oberve that 
$$m-o = -\frac i2a-\frac12 b+\frac{1+i}2c$$
and 
$$n-o = -\frac 12a+\frac i2 b+\frac{1-i}2c$$
and hence indeed $ m-o = i(n-o)$.

Comment: Why is alpha (1+i) / 2  ?

Comment: Also, is there a way to prove this without complex numbers - e.g. using symmetry?

Comment: @rtukkine: To reach M you can do the following: start at A ($a$), go towards $C$ (i.e., in direction $c-a$) for half the distance (reaching the point $a + \frac12(c-a)$), then take a left turn and go the same distance (reaching $a + \frac12(c-a) + i\frac12(c-a)$). This is the point $a + \frac{1+i}{2}(c-a)$, and in this the above answer has put $\alpha = \frac{1+i}{2}$. The $i$ comes from the left-turn (multiplication by $i$ is counterclockwise rotation by 90°).

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose two exterior semicircles in our approach. See the figure bellow.
[image: TriangleSemicircles]

Note that CJOK is a paralelogram, that $\angle CJO$ is external of $\triangle JAO$ and that $\angle CKO$ is external of $\triangle KOB$.
Note also that $\triangle MJO$ and $\triangle OKN$ are congruent, therefore 
$$MO = ON.$$
Using $\triangle MJO$ we get:
$$\alpha + \beta + 90^{\circ} + \theta + \gamma = 180^{\circ} \Rightarrow$$
$$\alpha + \beta + \theta + \gamma = 90^{\circ}$$
But as $\angle AOB$ is a straight angle and $\alpha + \beta + \theta + \gamma = 90^{\circ}$ we can conclude that $\angle MON$ is a right angle.

You can use a similar approach when semicircles are not exterior.

Comment: How do you know that CJOK is a paralelogram?

Comment: @rtukkine. The line segment connecting midpoints of two sides of a triangle is parallel to the third side and its length is half of the length of the third side.

Answer (score 0):

By "mathematically" do you mean by coordinates as opposed to geometry?  By coordinates, you can let $A=(-1,0), B=(x,y), C=(1,0)$ by rotation, translation, and scaling.  Then $M=(0,-1), N= (\frac{x+y+1}2,\frac{x+y-1}2)O=(\frac x2,\frac y2)$.  Now you can check.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @rtukkine:  I have shown the coordinates of points $O,M,N$ in the plane.  You can now check whether the distances match and whether the angle is a right angle by checking whether the slopes of the sides multiply to $-1$